# Enable Promiscous mode in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, networking, configuration, network-interface

How to enable promiscuous mode on network adapter. I have tried by adding `PROMISC=yes` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ensxxx`
but no effect even after network restart or rebooting the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CentOS 7 /usr/share/doc/initscripts-9.49.24/sysconfig.txt says:

> ```
>  No longer supported:
>  PROMISC=yes|no (enable or disable promiscuous mode)
>  ALLMULTI=yes|no (enable or disable all-multicast mode)
> ```

So for enabling you have to run:

```
ip link set ethX promisc on
```

Or if you want to happen on boot you can use `systemd` service `rc-local`.
Put the above line in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` (don't forget to change ethX with your proper device), then:

```
chmod u+x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
systemctl enable rc-local
systemctl start rc-local
```

Comment: Is there a reason why RedHat kicked out these options? Especially the PROMISC setting is quite useful!

Comment: @AxelBeckert, I really don't know why.